# MySQL autocommit vs. begin_transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

This is my (with little pseudo-) code:

```
$this->db = new mysqli ( $host, $user, $dbpw, $database );
try {
     $this->db->mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
     $sql = 'SOME SQL STATEMENT';
     $this->db->execute( $sql );
     $this->db->mysqli->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo($e);
   $this->db->mysqli->rollback();
}
```

db-class has some enhancements i need but is capable of using the complete mysqli-class.

i have 2 questions.

a. why cant i start the transaction with

```
$this->db->mysqli->begin_transaction();
```

its throwing unknown method error. i really dont understand that.

b. do i have to use

```
$this->db->mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
```

?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php  wasn't available until PHP 5.5

Comment: Also you instantiate `$this->mysqli` and then try to use `$this->db->mysqli`

Comment: @ jszobody that is a copy&pase error, corrected. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. Because `mysqli::begin_transaction` appeared in [PHP 5.5.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php). Your PHP version is lower it seems.

b. Depends on your requirements. Enabling `autocommit` will make MySQL commit transaction automatically and begin another one after executing each SQL statement.